# Communication between two winform application using WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

I have two different winform application, App1 and app2. App1 calls the exe of app2 (using DOS command window) and sends a message to start the app2. The app2 starts executing and once it finishes its task it sends back the message to app1 that the execution was successful. How can I acheieve this functionality using WCF. earlier the same code was written in foxpro and this finc was achieved using memory management.

Comment: WOW you didn't just say `FoxPro` that's one old language.. are you saying that the winform application is a FoxPro windows application..? what are you planning to do in regards to using WCF are you going to make this a service application instead.. ?

Comment: Yes that application was built up in Foxpro but now we are migrating the code from Foxpro to C#.net 4.0.

Comment: Ok I was just making sure.. I thought I was having a nightmare form my old Clipper / FoxPro coding days.. lol

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is peer-to-peer communication, where 2 applications (which may or may not be running on the same machine) send each other messages asynchronously. This is the way chat programs such as MSN Messenger work.

There's a "simple" tutorial about [peer-to-peer communication using WCF at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690929.aspx).

Mind you, this is not as easy as it sounds. You may prefer to [just send messages using Windows' `SendMessage`](http://boycook.wordpress.com/2008/07/29/c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. App 1 should be the server as there are many application like app2 and all should be executed in sequence, Once app2 gets executed then app3 execution is called from app 1 and soo. All the application are on the same system. Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, and what the best is depends on so many variables that it is impossible to answer your question. Seek the help of one of your company's architects or senior developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is just conceptual how to achieve this:

You need to implement WCF service. 
There are many ways how to do this task. One of this should be like this.

App1 calls service method and tell that app2 need to executed. App1 could than wait for the response.

App2 from time to time pings service to see if it needs to be executed.
App2 finished its job and call service method to tell that it was done.

App1 will get the response when it was finished.

Other option is not to implement request/response but to ping service from App1 to see if App2 did its job.

For how to implement WCF service see, for example: http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-Getting-Started.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot.  App 1 should be the server as there are many application like app2 and all should be executed in sequence, Once app2 gets executed then app3 execution is called from app 1 and soo. All the application are on the same system. Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

on one side instanciate a "server"

```
UIIServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(UIInterop));
UIIServiceHost.Open();
```

where UIInterop is a class implementaing IUIInterop that is a Service Contract

```
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IUIInterop {
    [OperationContract]
    void SetControlValue (UIControl c);
}

[DataContract]
public class UIControl {        
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

[Generate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx) a proxy class => UIInteropClient

on the other side implement a client using the proxy class

```
using ( UIInteropClient proxy = new UIInteropClient("nameDependingOfAppConfig") ) {
    proxy.SetControlValue(new UIControl {});
}
```

===== EDIT =====

the name of classes and interfaces only reflect my lack of imagination